# VB Script to open all Excel Files in a folder and run macros present in them

Tags: excel, vbscript

I'm trying to get to a VB Script that opens every Excel file in a given folder, runs the macro written in them (the macro is written as `Workbook_Open()` so it executes automatically) and the closes the files.

Currently, I have this code I have pasted below, but it does not work. It simply shows the messages that it has completed opening on macros, but does nothing to the workbooks.

```
OpenAllFiles()
MsgBox "Completed opening all Excel files in the folder."

Sub OpenAllFiles()

    dim fso
    dim thisfolder
    dim allfiles

    Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    set fso= Wscript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    set thisfolder = fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\ad6975\Desktop\Project\02 2014 IC\04 IC4\02 Goal Reporting\Test")
    set allfiles = thisfolder.Files

    Dim XL
    Set XL = CreateObject("excel.application") 

    For each onefile in allfiles
        if (onefile.type = "Microsoft Office Excel 97-2003 Worksheet" Or onefile.type = "Microsoft Excel Worksheet") then

            Dim XLWkbk
            Set XLWkbk = XL.Workbooks.Open(onefile)
            XL.DisplayAlerts = False
            Call XLWkbk.SaveAs(onefile.Path, 56, , , , , ,2)
            XLWkbk.Close
            Set XLWkbk = Nothing

        end if
    Next

    XL.Quit
    Set XL = Nothing 

End Sub
```

Comment: Does your macro work when you manually open one of the files? Are you sure it's even entering your `If` block? Test your script using a single workbook and make sure your `Open()` and `SaveAs()` statements are executing.

Comment: Make sure that no instances of excel are running. Check the taskmanager... often during the writing of such scripts there will be some error in the vbs leading to an excel.application object never being closed and this can lead to problems later.

Comment: SaveAs(onefile.Path, 56, , , , , ,2) - what does this section of the code mean? I tried googling it, but noone seems to be using this format.